# when there is pipe, how to deal with permission with sudo

Tags: shell, permissions, pipe

if the command is with a pipe, how to deal with  permission problem with sudo
the following command

```
sudo -u liy echo "update moz_cookies set value='f1=40000000&f3=40000&fv=11.2.202' where name='PREF' and host='.youtube.com';"|sqlite3 /user/liy/home/.mozilla/firefox/dd1pkryp.default/cookies.sqlite
```

leads to problem:

```
cannot open directory /user/liy/home/.mozilla/firefox/: Permission denied
```

how to deal with this? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `sudo` on the command doing the modifying:

```
echo 'some SQL' | sudo sqlite3 /some/database.db
```

You might even consider using a heredoc:

```
sudo sqlite3 /some/database.db <<ENDOFSQL
    -- SQL here; you can even use multiple lines!
ENDOFSQL
```